# I get an error message saying "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" when trying to rig with automatic weights

Tags: rigging

I can't use automatic weights because it won't work. I tried using "Merge by distance" because according to an answer on a different question that would make it work. It didn't. So what do I do now?

Comment: check normals, check for interior faces, make sure that scale was applied, check for non-manifold behavior, and if that all fails add your blend file to your question. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: how do i do those things? the only thing i know out of those things is applying scale

Comment: select the model. Go into edit mode. Deselect all. On the top menu bar there is a _Select_ menu.  It has a _Select by trait_ submenu.  Try _Interior Faces_.  If there are any they'll be selected and you should probably delete them.  Deselect all and try _Non-Manifold_.  Fix any problems that come up.

Comment: please share your file so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: all deleting non manifold vertices does is just gradually destroy the model and it still doesnt rig